# Redirect output of running program into a file that can then be analysed

Tags: linux, bash, stdout, io-redirection

I'm relatively inexperienced with bash scripting so I'm not sure if this is possible, but basically I'd like to write a bash script that

- runs my program, which periodically prints logs to stdout
- save all of the logs in a file
- stop running the program, and analyse the logs

Is this possible? The program can be run in terminal using `./program -c config_file.txt -v`

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)).  By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Comment: this is not a question.  Well, the answer to question as posted is "yes".

Comment: I believe all of your questions would have been answered immediately with a basic search. You should ask a specific question for a particular programming problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Comment: I have asked a new question that is more specific, but I was asking because the answers I've found did not work for me, and I thought it might be my specific situation that was not feasible.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect stdout to file in bash script for example you can alter your  script

`echo 'your output`'

To

```
echo 'your output' >> logfile
```